# How to evaluate the line integral $\int_C (y-z)\,dx+(z-x)\,dy+(x-y)\,dz$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How to evaluate the line integral $\int_C (y-z)\,dx(z-x)\,dy(x-y)\,dz$.

The curve $C$ is the intersection of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ and the plane $x-z=1$.

I am really stuck on how to to do this problem, I am wondering if Stokes is at all useful but I'm not sure. I can kind of visualize the curve it is going to be an ellipse I think. Like cutting a soda can with a sheet of paper and then analyzing the rim. But as to actually calculating the thing I am stumped.

Comment: x=cost,y=sint,z=cost-1,0<=t<=2pi. etc

Comment: Could you explain that parametrisation please?

Comment: @Sean You have $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, so just put $x=\cos(t)$ and $y=\sin(t)$...

Comment: But I thought it would be an ellipse so wouldn't you need something else not a circle?

Comment: Nevermind I got it just had a eureka moment :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** I think that Stokes' theorem is overkill here. We can get a simple parametrization: $${\bf r}(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, -1+\cos t), \quad 0 \leq t< 2\pi,$$and all the functions involved are simple too. Just write ${\rm d}x = -\sin t\,{\rm d}t$, etc, substitute and compute. Use and abuse of periodicity. A lot of terms should cancel out, it seems.

Comment: I don't understand that parametrization wouldn't have to be some coefficient before the $x,y$ terms because it is elliptical. Also how did you figure out the $z$ term? Thanks.

Comment: Nice! The answer would then be $2 \pi$. Vote up!

Small note, the range should be $0 \le t < 2\pi$.

Comment: Is the final answer $2\pi$ by the way that is what I calculated.

Comment: Any curve in the cylinder can be parametrized by $(\cos t, \sin t, z(t))$, so as to satisfy $x^2+y^2=1$, there's no constraint on $z$ so far. But the curve is on the plane, so it must satisfy $x(t)-z(t)=1$, that is, $\cos t - z(t) = 1$, from this we get $z(t) = -1+\cos t$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Simply the expression

$$
\big(y-z\big)\big(z-x\big)\big(x-y\big)
$$

We get
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\big(y-z\big)\big(z-x\big)\big(x-y\big)
&=&  \big(y-x+\underbrace{x-z}_{1}\big)\big(\underbrace{z-x}_{-1}\big)\big(x-y\big)\\
&=& \big(x+y-1\big)\big(x-y\big)\\
&=& \big(x-y\big)^2 - \big(x-y\big)\\
&=& \underbrace{x^2+y^2}_{1} - 2xy - x + y\\
&=& 1 - 2xy - x + y.
\end{array}
$$

Comment: there is a typo in the question, look at the title